# jena doesn't use LocationMapper on owl-imports

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

I have a ttl file with owl-imports clause like

```
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 

<http://test/data.ttl>
  a       owl:Ontology ;
  owl:imports <file:///Users/tht/workspace/jenatest/test_course.ttl> ;
  owl:versionInfo "tht testing owl:imports"^^xsd:string .
```

When test_course.ttl file exists, FileManager.get().readModel loads the model, the other ttl is imported and sparql queries work fine. But if i remove the file and use FileManager.get().setLocationMapper().addAltEntry() to redirect to another existing file, the model is not what i expect and the sparql queries return no results.

So owl-imports works fine, but it seems like jena is not using LocationMapper when importing? or could it be my mapping uris are incorrect? I'm using something like

```
mapper.addAltEntry("file:///Users/tht/workspace/jenatest/test_course.ttl",
"file:///Users/tht/workspace/jenatest/test_course.redirected.ttl")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OntModel`s have their own `FileManager` for handling owl:imports.

This, and the LocationMapper,  are accessed via the OntModel's DocumentManager:

```
model.getDocumentManager().addAltEntry(..., ...)
```

and other APIs calls.

Comment: thanks Andy - based on this hint I managed to use my custom mapper as
model.getDocumentManager().getFileManager().setLocationMapper(mapper);